# How to start Chromedriver in verbose mode - Selenium Eclipse

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, osx-mavericks

I just installed OSX 10.9 on my mac and ever since then my Chromedriver is not working when I try to run tests.

The error I get is that "chrome was killed".

Everybody keeps mentioning that it works when you set Chromedriver to --verbose mode but I have no idea how to do that.

Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to clarify what language you are using since selenium-webdriver supports many languages (ex Ruby, C#, etc.).

Comment: I am using Java, sorry for the late response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To fix this issue, you can download the latest Chromedriver version 2.6 which resolves this issue.

Link - http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

Answer (score 11):

Here's a script that creates the executable you'll need, `cd` to the directory where chromedriver is, then paste this into your console:

```
cat <<EOF>chromedriververbose
echo "running chromedriver --verbose \$*"
\$(dirname \$0)/chromedriver --verbose \$*
EOF

chmod +x chromedriververbose
```

That'll create an executable script called `chromedriververbose` that you can point your tests at rather than `chromedriver`.

Alternatively, you could rename `chromedriver` to `chromedriversilent` and then call the above script `chromedriver` and point it to `chromedriversilent` for drop-in replacement.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me.  I do, however, have a different error.  "Fatal error: The environment you requested was unavailable."

Answer (score 1):

I did the following from within the python console to test the verbose thing:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service_args=["--verbose"])
```

It seemed to do the trick. Not ideal but it works for now.

Comment: This managed to open the page however it's impossible to close Chrome without forcing quit and the page keeps hanging, it never finishes loading.  It's better than before however

Answer (score 0):

You can set command line flags in the capabilities (Java example)

```
capability = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capability.setCapability("chrome.switches",
    Arrays.asList("--verbose"));
webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(url), capability);
```

However I'm not seeing this actually solve the problem on my end, I still get

`org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: was killed`

Comment: Where you instantiate your driver.  If you are using a ChromeDriver (and not a RemoteWebDriver), you will pass it into the driver.

Comment: I am using ChromeDriver and not a RemoteWebDriver, would you be able to give me an example of this using ChromeDriver?

Comment: chrome.switches is used to pass arguments to Chrome itself and not the chromedriver executable. To pass args to chromedriver from Java code, you use ChromeDriverService. However, the current implementation of ChromeDriverService does not support passing --verbose. I've created a patch for that [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6473).