# Starting ChromeDriver in Verbose mode - Node / JS

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm attempting to update 'node-huxley' to start Chrome Web driver in verbose mode, to hopefully avoid the issues caused by upgrading to OSX Mavericks.

The code in question is as follows:

```
browser = webdriver.Capabilities.chrome();

driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .usingServer(serverUrl)
    .withCapabilities(browser)
    .build();
```

- https://github.com/chenglou/node-huxley/blob/master/source/browser.js

I'm struggling to find documentation on how to add command arguments ('--verbose') to the Chrome Driver.

Comment: Hi. Could you submit an issue to the repo please? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start chromedriver in verbose mode by doing the following:

```
cd <location of chromedriver>

mv chromedriver chromedriversilent

cat <<EOF>chromedriver
echo "running chromedriversilent --verbose $*"
\$(dirname \$0)/chromedriversilent --verbose $*
EOF

chmod +x chromedriver

open chromedriver
```

Question also answered here: [How to start Chromedriver in verbose mode - Selenium Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19543444/how-to-start-chromedriver-in-verbose-mode-selenium-eclipse)